# Cannot login to Azure Account from az login - admin enabled MFA

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

In azure pipelines of Azure DevOps need to use az login to get into azure account. Getting error that admin has enabled MFA and hence cannot login.

Do not want to use:

```
az login -u "username" -p "password"
```

Also don't want to implement Service Principal as feel that would be overkill.

How to login with az login from Azure DevOps when MFA is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of:

```
az login --use-device-code
```

Note: to avoid any mishaps set the subscription you want to use with:

```
az account set --subscription "subscription here"
```

So you have:

```
az login --use-device-code
az account set --subscription "subscription here"
```

It will then generate a url which you can enter into your browser with the generated device code. The other line will set the subscription you want to work with.

This is an intermittent solution as it is not fully automated in that you have to manually open the url and enter the device code. At least though your pipelines can still execute.

As soon as I have a way to automate the process or have a more effective solution will update the answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.